# Square and Sum of User Inputted List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers, math-functions

I want to print the sum and a squared version of an inputted list by a user. I am able to get the sum but not the list printed out squared. Ex. 1,2,3,4,5 .... 1,4,9,16,25

```
import math

#This defines the sumList function
def sumList(nums):

   total = 0
   for n in nums:
      total = total + n
   return total

def squareEach(nums):
   square = []
   for number in nums:
        number = number ** 2
   return number

 
#This defines the main program
def main():

   #Introduction
   print("This is a program that returns the sum of numbers in a list.")
   print()

   #Ask user to input list of numbers seperated by commas
   nums = input("Enter a list element separated by a comma: ")
   nums = nums.split(',')

   #Loop counts through number of entries by user and turns them into a list
   List = 0
   for i in nums:
        nums[List] = int(i)
        List = List + 1

   SumTotal = sumList(nums)
   Squares = squareEach(nums)
 
 
   #Provides the sum of the numbers in the list from the user input
   print("Here is the sum of the list of numbers {}".format(SumTotal))
   print("Here is the squared version of the list {}".format(Squares))

main()
```

Comment: While I realize this is an exercise in very rudimentary programming, you should also consider learning about built-in methods related to lists as well as list comprehensions as an ext step in your learning process.

Comment: My advice is to do your homeworks on your own. Otherwise you will not learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not getting the square of the numbers because your function **def** **squareEach(nums)** returns the square of the last number entered. For ex, if you entered 1,2,3,4 it would return 16 since 4^2=16. Change your squaring function to this-

```
def squareEach(nums):
   square = []
   for number in nums:
        number = number ** 2
        square.append(number)
   return square
```

For every square of the number computed, append to the list and return the list to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def squareEach(nums):
   square = []
   for number in nums:
       number = number ** 2
       square.append(number)
   return square
```

That should fix your function.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you

```py
def squareEach(nums):
   square = []
   for number in nums:
        square.append(number ** 2)
   return square
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
dict_square = {}
list_square =[]

for val in lst:
    dict_square[val] = val**2
    list_square.append(val**2)

print(sum(lst))     # 27 using the sum inbuilt method
print(list_square)  # [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
print(dict_square)  # {2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49}
```